# Is it possible to change the speed of HTML's <marquee> tag?

Tags: html, marquee

When one marquee leaves the screen then after a short time gap it enters from another side.
Is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: Please be aware that the marquee tag was never standard HTML and is deprecated.

Comment: @Orbling - Marquee is not deprecated. It's impossible to deprecate something that wasn't once standard.

Comment: @Alohci It's use is deprecated within the browsers that support it, the standard obviously does not deprecate it - as it is not part of the standard to begin with.

Answer (score 54):

```html
<marquee behavior=scroll direction="left" scrollamount="5">Your message here</marquee>
```

scrollamount controls the speed of text: higher the value higher is the scrolling speed

Answer (score 32):

we can control the scrolling speed by using the `scrollamount` attribute,

Example:

```
<marquee scrollamount="30">scrolling fast</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount="2">scrolling slow</marquee>
```

note:if you specify the minimum number, the scrolling speed will be reduce vice versa

Comment: this is perfectly working for me , as i used before scrolldelay that is used for speed delay in miliseconds!!!! Thanks

Answer (score 9):

**This attribute takes the time in milliseconds.**

Delay : 100 Milliseconds

```
<marquee scrolldelay="100">Scrolling text</marquee>
```

Delay : 400 Milliseconds

```
<marquee scrolldelay="400">Scrolling text</marquee>
```

Answer (score 7):

There isn't specifically an attribute to control that. Marquee isn't a highly reliable tag anyways. You may want to consider using jQuery and the .animate() function. If you are interested in pursuing that avenue and need code for it, just let me know.

Comment: There isn't an attribute to control that? Then what was the other posted answer about? Hmm...

Comment: He's right, technically: `scrolldelay` slows the entire animation, not specifically the delay between when the text scrolls off one edge and reappears on the other. See the examples on that very webpage.

Comment: @jcolebrand this **is**...was the answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can change the speed of marquee tag using **scrollamount** attribute.

It accepts integer values 6 being the default speed, so any value lower then 6 will slow down the marquee effect.

Example :

```
<marquee scrollamount=4>Scrolling text</marquee>
```

Read more : http://code2care.org/pages/marquee-tag-scrollamount/

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE_SCROLLAMOUNT.html

P.S : Avoid using marquee!

Comment: Marquee is really easy to use, but too blinking, even in low speed. What's good alternative to marquee?

Answer (score 4):

`scrolldelay="number"`

Comment: See also Google or any of the myriad returns, such as: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE.html

Comment: that will just slow it down, not reduce the time between 'refreshes'

Comment: Also consider Googling **"don't use marquee tag"** for the many good reasons, understood since the late 'Nineties, why you may wish to avoid using this particular feature of HTML...

Answer (score 4):

You can Change the speed by adding scrolldelay

```html
<marquee style="font-family: lato; color: #FFFFFF" bgcolor="#00224f" scrolldelay="400">Now the Speed is Delay to 400 Milliseconds</marquee>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Order to increase speed of your Marquee text you just need to add like this in your code below:

```
<marquee scrollamount="Integer number">scrolling fast</marquee>
```

Answer (score 2):

To increase scroll speed of text use attribute

```
scrollamount
OR
scrolldelay
```

in the 'marquee' tag. place any integer value which represent how fast you need your text to move

Answer (score 1):

I just do:

```
<marquee scrollamount="A number">Text here</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use scrollamount with an integer:
The higher the scrollamount value, the faster the text.

```html
<marquee scrollamount="1">SLOW TEXT</marquee>
<marquee>DEFAULT SPEED TEXT</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount="10">FAST TEXT</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount="20">Faster text</marquee>
```

Default scrollamount speed is 6.

```html
<marquee>Text</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount="6">Text</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount="30">Quick text</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount="90">Very Quick text</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<marquee scrollamount="1">SLOW TEXT</marquee>
<marquee>DEFAULT SPEED TEXT</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount="10">FAST TEXT</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount="20">Faster text</marquee>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: hi try this url https://www.w3schools.in/html-tutorial/marquee-tag/

Answer (score 0):

```
         <body>
         <marquee direction="left" behavior=scroll scrollamount="2">This is basic example of marquee</marquee>
         <marquee direction="up">The direction of text will be from bottom to top.</marquee>
         </body>
```

use scrollamount to control speed..

Answer (score -2):

On HTML5 the scrollamount and the scrolldelay attributes do not work. They are depricated attributes.

Comment: Where are those attributes deprecated?

Comment: please add html5 documentation to support your statements, it will help SO members